# Angular 2 cli compiles file, but error on browser Unhandled Promise rejection: Token must be defined

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I have a Angular 2 app created and running on development computer (lets say PC1), no error and no issues. PC1 is where app got created using the Angular CLI.

But if I get the latest code from another development computer (lets say PC2). if I say ng serve I get bellow warning.

WARNING in ./~/@angular/router/src/router_module.js
303:51-71 "export 'LOCATION_INITIALIZED' was not found in '@angular/common'
webpack: Compiled with warnings.

When I run it on the browser (Chrome), I get below error and app does not work.

zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Token must be defined! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Token must be defined! at new ReflectiveKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47642…, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Token must be defined!↵    at new Reflectiv…calhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:35600:37) [angular]", __zone_symbol__message: "Token must be defined!"}
 Error: Token must be defined!
    at new ReflectiveKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47642:19) [angular]
    at KeyRegistry.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47695:39) [angular]
    at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47660:35) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:100568:102) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65909:52) [angular]
    at RouterInitializer.appInitializer (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72616:48) [angular]
    at new ApplicationInitStatus (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:45643:45) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:483:36) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65892:76) [angular]
    at NgModuleFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65860:18) [angular]
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:46066:61 [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:35600:37) [angular]
zone.js:422 
ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined! Error: Token must be defined! at new…, rejection: ZoneAwareError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask}

[image: below is the screenshot of the errr]

Comment: Check that you aren't using different versions of angular-cli, node, and npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error just started cropping up today for me when I upgraded an app to @angular@4.0.0-beta.8 (while using @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.32.3.

Dropping back down to @angular@4.0.0-beta.7 seems to have solved it.